# I am only able to replace the first quotation mark in my str

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Code:

```
 var myPattern:RegExp = /\"/;

 trace(a.replace(myPattern, "\\\""));

<TEXTFORMAT LEADING=\"2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">sdfdsfdsf</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

above im using that regular expression to escape the " in the string. however it only does it for the first "

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the global flag.  See the docs for the [replace](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace()) method.

```
 var myPattern:RegExp = /\"/g;
```