# Convert a smiley tag like :mysmiley red: to <i class="mysmiley red"></i> in php

Tags: php

I would like to convert a textarea mesage that have been posted by using tags like `:mysmiley red:` with `<i class="mysmiley red"></i>` in php. The text area may have some other text like i eat rice `:mysmiley red:` but i want to convert the portion of that have been inside `:` and rest will be place as it is.

Comment: Good job Googling "replace string PHP". Was it really any faster to create an SO profile and type up the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am only able to replace the first quotation mark in my str](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392846/i-am-only-able-to-replace-the-first-quotation-mark-in-my-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use str_replace function

```
$body = str_replace(':mysmiley red:', '<i class="mysmiley red"></i>', $body);
```

You can also use arrays:

```
$ar1 = [':mydog blue:', ':mysmiley red:'];
$ar2 = ['<i class="mydog blue"></i>', '<i class="mysmiley red"></i>'];
$body = str_replace($ar1, $ar2, $body);
```

Comment: my bad what about if there are many colon like :mysmiley red: :mydog blue: etc

Comment: @user109640 Sure you can create a regex to do that, but think about it - is that *really* what you want? To have users be unable to type `:anything :` without is screwing up? `I have three daughters:melissa, kayla and christine. They're pretty cool. I also have a wife: Shannon` would be `<i class="melissa, kayla and christine. They're pretty cool. I also have a wife"></i>`

Comment: ok will try using your suggestion but now i am unable to vote up your answer as i am using in opera obile. Thank you anyway